# Mediawiki: in a link, pass parameter to template mediawiki, without transclusion

Tags: php, syntax, parameter-passing, mediawiki, wiki-markup

Here's a wiki syntax challenge!

Since asking [Mediawiki: Same section with multiple names (section aliases/synonyms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085676/mediawiki-same-section-with-multiple-names-section-aliases-synonyms), I've developed a more specific query as I feel like I'm closer to a solution that works the way I want it to:

I want to, in a link, pass a parameter to a template WITHOUT transcluding the full article.

```
[[ Template:Interrupts Code Examples|pagename={{PAGENAME}} ]]
```

Except this creates a link to an article named `pagename=Name_of_page_you're_on` instead of passing a parameter.

Transcluding the article, the parameter is passed successfully, but I just want a **link** to pass the parameter to the template.

For more context,

Using `#ifexists` I can generate a "code examples compilation" page that defaults to sections with headings "Example One" and "Example Two" when the names aren't given, but I also want them to be section linkable and show up with the appropriate headings depending on where the comes in from:

```
"EIMSK" and "Example Two"
"EICRA" and "Example Two"
"Example One" and "PCMSK0"
"Example One" and "PCMSK1"
"Example One" and "PCMSK2"
"Example One" and "PCICR"
```

Is this too terribly convoluted and I should just manually compile these pages? Is this possible?

My current solution is to have

```
"PCMSK0"
{{example one code}}
"PCMSK2"
{{example one code}}
"EICRA"
{{example two code}}
etc.
```

which is far from ideal since then the compilation of code examples page is just one [giant long mess](http://narwhaledu.com/AVRwiki/index.php?title=Interrupts_Code_Examples).

I am open to writing a MediaWiki extension in PHP if someone can give me some psuedocode to work off of.

Comment: No matter how many times I read this question I can't understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  This code `[[ Template:Interrupts Code Examples|pagename={{PAGENAME}} ]]` creates a link with the display text of "pagename=..." which I don't think is what you want at all, right?

Comment: Right, I am trying to pass a parameter (the current pagename) to a template (interrupts code examples), thus generating a section on the template named (pagename) so that I can link to it. Sorry it's unclear, I think maybe I should just do it by hand it's become so convoluted! Hah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: This may be only a partial answer.  I'll post it anyway, in case it is of some use.*

It you're simply trying to link to another page on your wiki with custom query parameters, use one of the [URL data magic words](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#URL_data) (`localurl`, `fullurl`, `canonicalurl`, etc.), like this:

```
[{{fullurl:Target page|pagename={{PAGENAMEE}}}} link text]
```

(Note the use of `{{PAGENAMEE}}` to [automatically URL-encode the source page name](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#URL_encoded_page_names).)

Note that the resulting link will be treated by MediaWiki as an external link, and will be formatted as such.  If the external link icon bothers you, a simple way to get rid of it is to wrap the link in a `<span>` or a `<div>` with `class="plainlinks"`.

It's possible to wrap all this in a template, e.g. like this:

Page *Template:Fancylink*:

```
<span class="plainlinks">[{{fullurl:{{{1}}}|pagename={{PAGENAMEE}}}} {{{2|{{{1}}}}}}]</span>
```

which would allow you to write your links as:

```
{{fancylink:Target page|link text}}
```

For an example of a similar template (albeit with extra bells and whistles added on top), see e.g. [Template:Edit on Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Edit), which links to a page with the `action=edit` parameter added to the URL.

However, this method alone will *not* cause the URL parameter `pagename=` you pass in the link to be substituted for `{{{pagename}}}` on the target page.  To make that happen, you'd probably need to write a custom MediaWiki extension.  This should be doable, but considerably more involved than just creating the links in the first page.

---

Alternatively, the "conventional" MediaWiki way of solving this kind of issue, given that the set of valid parameter values seems to be limited, would be to create a separate page for each value that simply transcludes the shared template, something like:

Page *Interrupts Code Example PCICR*:

```
{{Interrupts Code Example One|interrupt=PCICR}}
```

with *Template:Interrupts Code Example One* containing the actual example code, possibly with `{{{interrupt}}}` substituted for the interrupt name (or used for [things like `{{#switch:...}}`](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions)) in appropriate places.  To [create the individual pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151825/mass-upload-many-text-files-to-mediawiki), if there are many, you could use a [bot](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Bots) or the maintenance scripts [importTextFile.php](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportTextFile.php) or [edit.php](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Edit.php).